# NDK r16b standalone toolchain error: "/usr/bin/ld: this linker was not configured to use sysroots"

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, linker

I'm trying to build an app using Android NDK.
The compile went successfully but in the linking step it fails with error as below:

```
1> /usr/bin/ld: this linker was not configured to use sysroots
clang50++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm using

```
--sysroot=<MyNDKPath>/sysroot
```

And

```
-isystem <MyNDKPath>/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi
```

when compiling

Can anyone help me on resolving this ?

Comment: There isn't enough detail here. Can you explain how you generated your standalone toolchain and also share the command you used to build? It looks like one of these things was not done correctly (I'm guessing the latter).

Comment: I managed to fixed it by removing --gcc-toolchain argument from the linker. it seems that it points to the wrong toolchain.

Comment: @expee105 how did you remote it? I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a missing path to ld. I added it to the PATH environment variable inside Eclipse and it worked:

```
${ANDROID_NDK}\toolchains\aarch64-linux-android-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin
```